# Laravel getAttribute($key) as own model function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using the `getAttribute($key)` function in one of my models.

***Function:***

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    return parent::getAttribute($key) ??
       optional($this->project)->getAttribute($key);
}
```

The function returns all attributes of my model and adds attributes from a relationship (`$this->project`) to the model.

My problem is that this function runs everytime I'm using the model.
Is it possible to wrap this in a own function, for example:

***Model:***

```
public function myOwnFunction($key)
{
    return parent::getAttribute($key) ??
       optional($this->project)->getAttribute($key);
}
```

***Controller:***

`$projectTranslation->myOwnFunction($key);`

Comment: Like [Defining An Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)? "_that this function runs everytime I'm using the model_" How so?

Comment: @brombeer yes I tried that but then the `optional($this->project)->getAttribute($key)` no longer works.

Comment: @EsTeAa it should combine all attribute keys of my model and the relation `$this->project`.

Comment: What is the actual problem that it runs everytime you use the model? In your controller you could use the exact code you just supplied? For instance call $model->someProperty in controller and if model has a non null 'someProperty' it will return it, if not it will return $model->project->someProperty (with null fallback) ?

Comment: @ajthinking the problem is that the `getAttribute($key)` runs automatically when im returning the model to a view and I don't want this behavior everytime because I'm using Livewire to edit the model. When I'm wrap all in the `myOwnFunction($key)` and use this `$projectTranslation->myOwnFunction($key);` in my controller, the model doesn't return the '$model->project->someProperty' when some key is null.

Comment: Can you show you view code?